# Unpacking class definition to share variable names between objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

While there may be a better way to phrase the question, the idea is pretty simple.

I have two classes. Parcel and ParcelRequest. ParcelRequest is used in an API to request information about a Parcel with the given parameters and

Effectively, ParcelRequest requires all the same parameters as Parcel, but requires an additional `quantity` value.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Parcel(BaseModel):
    length: float
    width: float
    height: float
    weight: float


class ParcelRequest(BaseModel):
    length: float
    width: float
    height: float
    weight: float
    quantity: int
```

Is there a way to keep Parcel and ParcelRequest "in sync" whenever Parcel is modified?

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Parcel(BaseModel):
    length: float
    width: float
    height: float
    weight: float


class ParcelRequest(BaseModel):
    # unpack Parcel attributes here
    quantity: int
```

NOTE: In this particular example, we cannot alter the structure of the incoming request. Meaning, we cannot simply include a "parcel" attribute to ParcelRequest that references a Parcel object, as it would change the structure of the request.

The question is whether this can be done. But as a bonus, *should* this be done? My belief is that, while the API will stay up to date with Parcel as it evolves, a developer could unintentionally break the API by updating Parcel, unless treated carefully and without proper tests.

Comment: Why don't you just put a "pointer" to a Parcel in ParcelRequest?

Comment: @thebjorn Good question, I forgot to include this. There's a set requirement for how the incoming request body is structured. Using a pointer instead of the listed attributes would break that requirement.

Comment: A non-declarative approach might be a better option. `common = {'length': float, ...}`, then `Parcel = type('Parcel', (BaseModel,), common)` and `ParcelRequest = type('ParselRequest', (BaseModel,), dict(common, quantity=int))`. If `BaseModel` is a wrapper around some metaclass, you might be able to call that directly rather than calling `type`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't repeat yourself, phrase a class to inherit from:

```
class MetaParcel(BaseModel):
    length: float
    width: float
    height: float
    weight: float


class ParcelRequest(MetaParcel):
    quantity: int
```

Comment: So this is the obvious answer, but is this best practice? Since the intention of each model is different, does it make sense to extend them? Or do we not apply the same principles to data classes?

Comment: Say, it makes sense for us to add a bit of logic to our Parcel class. ParcelRequest now extends this logic. However, ParcelRequest is not intended to be used for anything other than a data model. ParcelRequest should not be required to extend functionality it has no intention to use or have logical use for.

Comment: @JustianMeyer: You may want to look into [data classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

Comment: @Jan I suspect `pydantic.BaseModel` is already implementing something like a dataclass. (In fact, the documentation discusses using a dataclass instead of `BaseModel`: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/dataclasses/).

Comment: That's not a meta class. It's a plain old parent class.

Comment: @chepner, that's correct. While their intention is very similar, there are some subtle differences. I think for the sake of code design we can treat them the same. Unless there's a property specific to dataclasses I may be missing.

Comment: This approach of inheritance is correct. If you really want attributes on parcel but not parcel request, use a common base class.